# Blockchain - Fabric - Cannot run peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I run the tutorial for installing Hyperledger Fabric - by following steps in the url

[https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/test_network.html]

However, when I want to try run command

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles "${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

I got error

> 2023-06-27 03:16:14.191 UTC 0001 ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /home/izyani/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo

I change my user to root, configure back the environment variable value - CLI Path, Fabric Conf Path, etc and run the command back, I manage to get the correct output

```
2023-06-27 03:16:59.524 UTC 0001 INFO [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200
```

How to make the above command run for the my user, not the root user?
FYI, I already configure my docker - so that my user will have the administrator mode by running command - `sudo usermod -aG docker myuser`

Another question is how to permanently set the environment value so that whenever I want to try it, I dont have to set the configuration again?

Thank you